# Usar selectores CSS para ocultar todo excepto un H3

Tags: css

Estoy modificando mediante css un widget the wordpress en el que hay un título de la noticia y un resumen. Resulta que el título tiene una clase asignada, pero el resumen sólo me aparece como " " (sin clase).

Así que quería seleccionar todo menos el título (un h3 con a) y había sacado [de aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35325911/using-css-selectors-to-hide-everything-but-first-ul-and-h3?newreg=47854b0a76094ef6b2aa5c427be9affd) algo como esto, pero resulta que consigo el efecto contrario (ocultar solo el H3 con el link a y dejar visible el resto):

```
.content.table-cell > :not(a) {
display: none !important;
}
```

¿Cómo puedo conseguirlo? Muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el código HTML relevante dentro de `table-cell`? Sin saber tu estructura HTML es imposible saber qué selector sería correcto o cómo está fallando el que ya tienes

Comment: Me temo que por el momento no vas a poder hacer esto mediante CSS, tendremos que esperar que la pseudo clase [:has()](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#relational) esté disponible.

Answer (score 2):

Haría falta que pusieras el código html, tal y como comenta Alvaro. 
Aunque no es la mejor opción, creo que podría servirte esto:

```
.content.table-cell {
display: none;
}
.content.table-cell > :not(a) {
display: block !important; /*block, inline-block, inline... */
}
```

Comment: Esto no funcionaría porque como el contenedor tendría `display:none`, independientemente del valor de los `display` de los elementos dentro del mismo, todo estará invisible. Lo puedes ver en este JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u98jymrw/

Comment: Ya veo. Sin tener el html es difícil imaginar la estructura para usar selectores, pero si, tienes razón, no funciona.